# How to remove default option in toolbar of react-draft-wysiwyg?

Tags: reactjs, editor, rich-text-editor, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

[image]

According my question, I want to remove some default toolbar option like a font family or emoji and remain only text style options. How to do that ?

For my editor.

```
<Editor
    editorState={editorState}
    wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
    onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
    toolbar={{
        inline: { inDropdown: true },
        list: { inDropdown: true },
        textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
        link: { inDropdown: true },
        history: { inDropdown: true },
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pass an array named `options` containing all options you need in the **toolbar** property. Here is an array with all available options:

`options: ['inline', 'blockType', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'list', 'textAlign', 'colorPicker', 'link', 'embedded', 'emoji', 'image', 'remove', 'history']`

And here is example containing only text style options and without font family

```
<Editor
    editorState={editorState}
    wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
    onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
    toolbar={{
        options: ['inline', 'blockType', 'fontSize', 'list', 'textAlign', 'history'],
        inline: { inDropdown: true },
        list: { inDropdown: true },
        textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
        link: { inDropdown: true },
        history: { inDropdown: true },
    }}
/>
```

For more information see: https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs

Comment: I appreciate your answer..but when putting inline in the options array their comes other unnecessary options like {},x*2,$ ..But how do I remove this ?

Comment: @Abhishekkumar You can control that by passing array `options` to the `inline` property. Example: `inline: { inDropdown: true, options: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'monospace', 'superscript', 'subscript'] }`

Comment: @Abhishekkumar Here is a list of all inline options `inline:{inDropdown:false,className:undefined,component:undefined,dropdownClassName:undefined,options:['bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','monospace','superscript','subscript'],bold:{icon:bold,className:undefined},italic:{icon:italic,className:undefined},underline:{icon:underline,className:undefined},strikethrough:{icon:strikethrough,className:undefined},monospace:{icon:monospace,className:undefined},superscript:{icon:superscript,className:undefined},subscript:{icon:subscript,className:undefined},}`